# How to get file name in Laravel without a path file

Tags: laravel, image, file-upload, filenames, filepath

I'm trying to upload an image file to the database. But, when it posted, it shows a full path of the image file (I use the `getClientOriginalName()` to get the filename).

**DSController.php**

```
public function createDS2(Request $request)
    {
        //dd($request->all());

        $imgName1 = $request->file('opsi_a')->getClientOriginalName() . '-' . time() . '.' . $request->file('opsi_a')->extension();
        $imgName2 = $request->file('opsi_b')->getClientOriginalName() . '-' . time() . '.' . $request->file('opsi_b')->extension();
        $imgName3 = $request->file('opsi_c')->getClientOriginalName() . '-' . time() . '.' . $request->file('opsi_c')->extension();
        $imgName4 = $request->file('opsi_d')->getClientOriginalName() . '-' . time() . '.' . $request->file('opsi_d')->extension();

        $data = new DS2;
        $data->pertanyaan = $request->input('pertanyaan');
        $data->opsi_a = $request->file('opsi_a')->move(public_path('image'), $imgName1);
        $data->opsi_d = $request->file('opsi_b')->move(public_path('image'), $imgName2);
        $data->opsi_b = $request->file('opsi_c')->move(public_path('image'), $imgName3);
        $data->opsi_c = $request->file('opsi_d')->move(public_path('image'), $imgName4);
        $data->kunci = $request->input('kunci');
        $data->save();
        return redirect('ds2');
    }
```

the image file in the database will show something like this :
`C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_kuis\public\image\hiu_press.png-1614165665.png`

how I can just save the `hiu_press.png-1614165665.png` in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way as @zia-yamin but different syntax.

```
$imgName1 = $request->file('opsi_a')->getClientOriginalName() . '-' . time() . '.' . $request->file('opsi_a')->extension();
$imgName2 = $request->file('opsi_b')->getClientOriginalName() . '-' . time() . '.' . $request->file('opsi_b')->extension();
$imgName3 = $request->file('opsi_c')->getClientOriginalName() . '-' . time() . '.' . $request->file('opsi_c')->extension();
$imgName4 = $request->file('opsi_d')->getClientOriginalName() . '-' . time() . '.' . $request->file('opsi_d')->extension();

$request->file('opsi_a')->move(public_path('image'), $imgName1);
$request->file('opsi_b')->move(public_path('image'), $imgName2);
$request->file('opsi_c')->move(public_path('image'), $imgName3);
$request->file('opsi_d')->move(public_path('image'), $imgName4);

$data = new DS2;
$data->pertanyaan = $request->input('pertanyaan');
$data->opsi_a = pathinfo($imgName1, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
$data->opsi_b = pathinfo($imgName2, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
$data->opsi_c = pathinfo($imgName3, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
$data->opsi_d = pathinfo($imgName4, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
$data->kunci = $request->input('kunci');
$data->save();
return redirect('ds2');
```

Answer (score 0):

store your file full path in `$stored_file` variable and then use this one:

```
$data->opsi_d = $request->file('opsi_b')->move(public_path('image'), pathinfo($imgName2)['basename']);
```

Also, you can use:

```
$file = Input::file('image');
$fileName = $file->move(public_path('image'), $imgName1->getOriginalFileName());
$fileName->image = $fileName ->getRealPath();
```

Comment: hi, sorry. I don't really understand what you mean. Could you please make an example? I'm still learning on laravel.

Answer (score 0):

> Use This Code:

```
if ($request->hasFile('file_name')) {
    $file_name = $request->file('file_name');
    $file_name = time() . $file_name->getClientOriginalName();
}
```